# How to get rid of a JQUERY APPEND GIve the following code

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, jqtouch

Given the following lines of code which is using JQTOUCH:

```
$('#customers').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(e, info){
    if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {                     
        $('.loadingscreen').css({'display':'block'});
        $(this).append($('<div> </div>').        
            load('/mobile/ajax/customers/ .info', function() {        
                $(this).parent().data('loaded', true); 
                $('.loadingscreen').css({'display':'none'});
            }));
    }
});
```

How can I get ride of the .append($(' ').
It used to be append($('loading') but I didn't need that and now it seems like a waste of processing time to have in the function.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(this).append($('<div> </div>').        
            load('/mobile/ajax/customers/ .info', function() {        
                $(this).parent().data('loaded', true); 
                $('.loadingscreen').css({'display':'none'});
            }));
```

becomes

```
 $(this).load('/mobile/ajax/customers/ .info', function() {        
                $(this).parent().data('loaded', true); 
                $('.loadingscreen').css({'display':'none'});
            });
```

Comment: That's what I thought but it errors :

missing ; before statement
[Break on this error] }));\n

Comment: This did it:    $(this).load('/mobile/ajax/customers/ .info', function() {        
       $(this).parent().data('loaded', true); 
       $('.loadingscreen').css({'display':'none'});
   });

Comment: You had one more ending bracket.